# ActionScript 3 Barcode Generator

Tags: actionscript-3, barcode

Does anyone know of any good Barcode Generator library for AS3? I need it really really bad. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: https://code.google.com/p/actionscript-barcode-generator/

It's a jQuery plug-in port to AS3.

Should comply with several barcode standards.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan and Teejay! This is exactly what I wanted, a library which is easy to read and not too heavy! I've just checked out the code and I'm trying to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

here is zxing library port [AS3 zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/actionscript)

> ZXing (pronounced "zebra crossing") is an open-source, multi-format
>   1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java, with ports
>   to other languages. Our focus is on using the built-in camera on
>   mobile phones to scan and decode barcodes on the device, without
>   communicating with a server. However the project can be used to encode
>   and decode barcodes on desktops and servers as well.

original see here: [zxing googlecode](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: It looks so interesting! Thank you very much bitmapdata.com. I'll really consider it in future. Thank you.